# Pi 3B addressable physical memory

Tags: pi-3, memory-split

Using valgrind, I have found a program (written by co-worker) receives a bus error:

`Non-existent physical address at address 0x4859008`

This had me wondering how physical memory was mapped. I read that the memory split between the gpu and cpu can be configured. I set this to the maximum allowed split, `gpu = 16M` and `arm = 992M`. By doing this, I thought that would increase the total number of physical addresses available to the CPU. I still receive the bus error, so either my logic is not correct or the increase was not enough.

My question is this: what is the maximum physical memory address available to the CPU?

EDIT: The issue with the program was resolved (a permissions issue). This question is about physical memory.

Comment: It might be helpful if you [edit] to explain what program you're trying to run (is this something from the repos, or your own program?) — I suspect the problem is probably that there is a programming error rather than exhausting your memory.

Comment: @Aurora0001 The program is something created by a coworker. The issue with the program is something I'm working on separately. I included the error since it's my motivation behind my question.

Comment: The maximum address possible on a Raspberry is 0x40000000. It can't address more than 1GB. It looks like you have a segfault in the code you're running or in valgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [BCM2835 Manual](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf), physical memory addressing ranges from `0x00000000` to `0x40000000`.

Physical addressing starts at `0x00000000` for the ARM processor. The VideoCore MMU will map a portion of the ARM physical address space to it's own bus address space within this range. This portion of memory must be no less than `16MB` and no greater than `944MB` using the default memory mapping. Any peripherals will be mapped from `0x20000000` to `0x20FFFFFF`.